# is there any problem with my procedure.i am using mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a procedure as shown below and it was throwing me error. all the tables and column names are correct. please help me with this.
[image]

Comment: The problem will be what the error message is telling you

Comment: `WHERE video_id = 'VideoID'` Quotes needed around strings in a query